# Handling Opencart 2.x Currency

Tags: opencart2.x

This is regarding currency conversion.

We have a website using Codeigniter on which we are using Opencart as a subset system for cart and checkout etc. So just like Opencart has a dropdown in the header to change currency rates.

We need to implement a dropdown in the header in Codeigniter (PHP Framework) so that it changes the currency in Opencart as well. By the way header is common b/w both Codeigniter and Opencart systems. Header resides under Codeigniter.

I have tried posting 'code' and 'redirect' variables to the currency function under controller in Opencart using Javascript and cURL. Basically trying to mimic Opencart dropdown functionality.

I have also tried setting the session variable: $_SESSION['default']['currency'] = 'EUR'; (for example)

Both ways do not work!

Is there a way we can change the currency from outside of Opencart? Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in file "system/library/currency.php" find

```
$this->set($this->config->get('config_currency'));
```

there you can set currency `$this->config->get('config_currency')` change to your variable

And in "catalog/controller/startup/startup.php" you can add currency for your session..

```
$this->session->data['currency'] = 'EUR';
```

Comment: Thanks for replying K. B., "system/library/currency.php" seems like a big help (have to refresh the page twice to get it to work) but there is no startup folder under "catalog/controller/". Also I searched for "$this->session->data['currency']" under the controller folder (all files) but could not find it! I am using Opencart 2.1.0.1

Comment: yes startup.php only from OC2.2 version. Currency session  in OC2.1  the same file "system/library/currency.php" under `public function set($currency) {`